# How to implement multi select drop-down in Angular 5 using TypeScript?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Please tell a method to add multi-select drop-down in Angular 5 using TypeScript. I am using WebStorm as IDE.

Answer (score 0):

how about use mat-select of material framework? look [here](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview), search for Multiple selection

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with WebStorm but the concept should be the same really. The important part is adding the `multiselect` property to the `select` input like so:

```
    <select multiselect multiple="multiple" 
            [formControlName]="question.key" 
            [id]="question.key" class="form-control" 
            [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': (!isValid && isTouched)}">
      <option *ngFor="let opt of question.options; let idx = index" [value]="idx">
        {{opt}}
      </option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

IN YOUR HTML PAGE

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]=" Sequences "
                                 [data]="sequences"
                                 [(ngModel)]="sequencesSelectedItems"
                                 [settings]="sequencesDropdownSettings"
                                 (onSelect)="onSequenceSelect($event)"
                                 (onSelectAll)="onSequenceSelectAll($event)">
        </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

IN YOUR COMPONENT

```
sequencesSelectedItems = [];
sequences = []
  sequencesDropdownSettings = {
    singleSelection: false,
    idField: 'id',
    textField: 'value',
    selectAllText: 'Select All',
    unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
    itemsShowLimit: 3,
    allowSearchFilter: true
  }; 
this.sequenceService.GetSequences().subscribe(res => {
      this.sequences = res;
    });
```

Data is the actual data that goes in the dropdown list to choose from
Placeholder is what you want your dropdown to say
ngModel is the array you want your selected items to go 
settings is the settings for the dropdown
onselect and onselectall are both methods you have to define to get different selection behaviors.